# How can withEventTimeOrder be used when referencing a view in DLT with UnityCatalog enabled

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables, databricks-unity-catalog

My setup:

I have two DLT Pipelines, say 'staging' and 'transform'.

- 'staging' is creating a streamingTable with autoloader from cloud_files. The structure of the data is messages with Calls and Responses. So every record can either be a Call or a Response and they CAN be linked by a messageId both have in common. The number of records is very big, so i want to keep 'staging' and 'transform' in seperate pipelines.
  Lets call the output table 'stream_ingest'
- 'transform' does transform the data. To reference the data from 'staging', we create a `@dlt.view()` on the table `stream_ingest` as our first dlt operation.
  One transformation includes a join of the two subsets of data to match Calls and Responses via the messageId. As we are dealing with a stream-stream join here, some caveats have to be considered:

  1. We have to set a watermark on the data to allow for state cleanup. As the Response to a message is supposed to arrive quickly, we can luckily use this pattern as intended.
  2. We have to set withEventTimeOrder as a pipeline cluster settings.
     (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/structured-streaming/delta-lake#process-initial-snapshot-without-data-being-dropped) )

Diagram:

```
+-------------+       +-------------+     
|  Pipeline   |       |  Pipeline   |    
|  'staging'  |       | 'transform' |    
+------+------+       +------+------+    
       |                     |           
       |                     |           
       v                     v           
+---------------+   +-----------------+  
|  dlt.table    |   |   dlt.view      |  
|'stream_ingest'|   | 'stream_ingest' |  
+---------------+   +--------+--------+  
                             |           
                             |           
                             v           
                    +-----------------+  
                    |    dlt.table    |  
                    | 'join_callResp' |  
                    +-----------------+
```

Until now, we created the pipelines with hive_metastore targets and this setup worked seamlessly.

Now to the problem:

We want to switch to pipelines to write to UnityCatalog targets.
But when we do, the dlt table 'join_callResp' suddenly throws the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
'withEventTimeOrder' is enabled on the delta source but cannot be supported in your current streaming query. 
The event time column in the query cannot be projected from delta source columns, 
which prevents Spark from sorting and processing the data with event time order. 
To fix the issue, update the event time to be a delta source column or a column that can be projected from delta columns.
```

Strangely, if we change the dlt.view('stream_ingest') to be a dlt.table, so fully copying from one pipeline to the other instead of just referencing, all works as expected again.
Both pipelines write to the same Catalog and Schema,

- Changing the dlt.view() to a dlt.table() resolves the issue, but now the data is duplicated for no reason.
- Removing the dlt.view() and simply creating the same spark.readStream() expression for the vie inside the logic of 'join_callResp' (instead of referencing the view), does not resolve the issue.

Comment: I have run into this issue as well. Seems to me like a bug in DLT's Unity Catalog integration which at the time of writing is still in Public Preview. I've brought this up in a support case with Databricks.